# Date Validation function in Standard SQL/BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, netezza

Do we have any Built-in function which can validate Dates by finding its match with provided regular expression?
For example : In Netezza , We have following syntax to achieve this functionality :

```
sqltoolkit..regexp_match_count(SRC.FILE_DATE, '^99[0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]$') = 1 THEN TO_DATE(SRC.FILE_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

I would like to have the similar SQL syntax to make my code run.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question. Do you simply want to run regex in BigQuery/SQL? If so, yes, this is possible  - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains. You could also just use date/time functions too: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date-functions

Comment: Thank you @GrahamPolley By running a simply regex my problem got solved. Thanks for pointing the corresponding documentation.